# Is it possible to created a collection on the dest based on a collection in source?

Tags: c#, automapper

Say I have

```
public class A 
{ 
  public List<int> Ids {get;set;}
}
public class B 
{ 
   public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}
public class Category 
{ 
   public string Name {get;set;} //will be blank on map
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}

var source = new A {...};

var b  = mapper.Map<A, B>(source);
```

so when mapped it will actually create a new collection on the `dest` but will map the ids based on what's in the source collection, other properties of the `dest` will be blank because there is nothing to map from.

How to setup the configuration to do this mapping?

Comment: What are your attempts to solve this? You have `MapFrom()` and `ResolveUsing()` on your disposal, have you used/tried these? If yes, how does these helped you (or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combination of `ForMember`, `MapFrom` and `ForAllOtherMembers`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                  {
                      cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
                         .ForMember(dest => dest.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ids));

                      cfg.CreateMap<int, Category>()
                         .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
                         .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
                  });
```

`MapFrom` will allow you to override the default mapping-by-name that AM normally does. As you can see in line 4, we can say that `Ids` in the source maps to `Categories` in the destination class.

But now you need to override how an `int` gets mapped, since that is the type of thing in `Ids`. With `MapFrom`, you don't (necessarily) have to provide a property for the source--the entire source itself can be the thing being mapped. So in line 7, we are mapping the `int`s that came from the mapping in line 4 and saying that they should map to the destination class' `CategoryId` property. Finally, we simply tell AM that we don't care to map any remaining properties in the target class by specifying the `ForAllOtherMembers` option.